# ¿Que significa "indios de güida"?

Tags: significado

A que hace referencia la palabra "güida", en contexto: *" Entonces, ya se entraban los indios de güida de los españoles. Se enterraban vivos. Los otros indios los tapaban; entonces, se morían asfixiados."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aunque no es una palabra **correcta** del español recuerdo que las personas mayores (los que hoy tendrían mas de 100 años) lo usaban mucho.

Es una deformación de la palabra **huida** y significa `huir despavorido`

La frase que describes se puede reescribir como

> Entonces, ya se entraban los indios **huyendo en pánico** de los españoles...

Comment: En México se dice a veces güevo para huevo.  Creo que da más impacto.  ¿Será parecido a eso?

Comment: Exactamente el mismo fenómeno @aparente001